# Is it possible to connect to macOS from iOS via bluetooth using CBPeripheral

Tags: ios, swift, macos, bluetooth, l2cap

I am trying to connect iOS and macOS with bluetooth.They are already connected via bluetooth but when I try to retrieve them programmatically in swift using CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral it doesn't list it.i am trying to open a peripheral.openL2CAPChannel(0x1001) with macOS but I cannot identify peripheral as macOS

Answer (score 1):

[Core Bluetooth](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/CoreBluetoothOverview/CoreBluetoothOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013257-CH2-SW1) is intended to connect between an iOS or macOS device on one side and an accessory on the other side. To connect between apps running on Apple devices, you may consider the [Multipeer Connectivity](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/multipeerconnectivity) framework.

Comment: Thanks for the info.Would it be possible to connect via CoreBluetooth.Any example available @pommy

Comment: @md12 Core Bluetooth provides additional support for Bluetooth Classic devices since iOS 13. I suspect this only includes other types of accessories and not iOS or macOS devices, but don't know for sure. Apple provides [a sample code project](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/using_core_bluetooth_classic).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. I've done it many times for Bluetooth Low Energy connections. The first few times I used https://github.com/noble/bleno to advertise my MacOS as a specific peripheral.

I've been slowly working on a Bluetooth peripheral library that can be run as a Swift command line runner, mostly for testing purposes.

https://github.com/RobotPajamas/SwiftyTeeth/issues/36
https://github.com/RobotPajamas/SwiftyTeeth/tree/feature/36-ble-peripheral/Sources/SwiftyTooth

It's not done yet, but I hope to get some time over the holidays to finish it up.